# Rename and merge [.netstandard] tags to [.net-standard]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Right now there are many different tags for .NET Standard e.g. [netstandard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard), [.net-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard) and sub-tags [netstandard1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard1.5), [.net-standard-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard-1.4), [netstandard1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard1.6), [.net-standard-1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard-1.5), [.net-standard2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard2.0), [netstandard2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard2)

These should be renamed and consolidated accordingly e.g. [netstandard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard) and [.net-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard) should be consolidated under one tag (I would suggest [.net-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard)).

All subtags should follow a consistent naming convention. IMO .net-standard-versionnumber where version number is majorversion.minorversion i.e [.net-standard-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard-2.0)

Comment: While I agree with merging, I think it would be better to use the name that developers will see in project files etc, so `netstandard1.0`, `netstandard2.0` etc.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with @Jon here. We generally prefer to use the official name of the product in the tags, and as best I can tell, that's ".NET Standard", so [.net-standard] seems like the logical choice for a tag (where dashes are used in lieu of spaces). Synonyms should address the issue of discoverability.

Comment: @JonSkeet possibly, but we'll end up with a mix then, unless we also create synonyms like `net40` or `net47` for the existing .NET Framework tags.

Comment: Happy to go with the majority, but personally I find myself writing "netstandard2.0" far more often than ".NET Standard 2.0".

Comment: @JonSkeet, That there are multiple ways which something is often written is the primary reason that synonyms exist. There's nothing wrong with having tags showing it both ways, as long as the tags are synonyms of each other. In fact, if there are multiple common ways to write it, then there *should be* such synonyms (as long as they don't conflict with some other project). However, IMO, the primary tag should be the official name, or as close to it as we can reasonably get using the characters available to tags.

Comment: Agreed that it should be `.net-standard` and `.net-standard-x.y` to follow our own naming, with all those other ones as aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaand it's gone.

[image]

Disappeared:

- [netstandard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard) ➡ [.net-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard)
- [netstandard1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard1.5) ➡ [.net-standard-1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard-1.5)
- [netstandard1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard1.6) ➡ [.net-standard-1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard-1.6)
- [netstandard2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netstandard2) ➡ [.net-standard2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard2.0)

Still alive:

- [.net-standard2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard2.0) ➡ [.net-standard-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-standard-2.0)

That's another 132 questions.

Comment: Okay... I've renamed and syn'd `.net-standard2.0` to `.net-standard-2.0` to keep it all consistent...

Comment: @JonClements [tag:status-completed]?